Likelihoods in both linear regression model and naive Bayesian model
The model in linear regression is
$y = \omega^T x + e$
, where x, y, e represent the feature, the target and the noise, respecively.
p(y|x, omega) is often termed the likelihood function for the linear regression model.
In naive Bayesian algorithm, p(x|y) is called likelihood function.
These two likelihood function is confusing, because the order of x and y are opposite. What is the explanation for these two likelihoods? Thanks.

In the logistic regression model, p(y|x, omega)  is termed conditional likelihood function, in which omega is the parameter.
In navive Bayesian classifier, p(x|y) is the likelihood function of features, since in this case the label is something that we can change. In naive Bayesian, we focus on the distribution of features in different classes.
